# Clojure expand reader macro

Tags: clojure

How can we find out what a reader macro does ?

For instance I know that a regex `#"abc"` is the same as `(re-pattern "abc")`.

However the following : `(macroexpand #"abc" )` yields `#"abc"`, so how can I go from the reader special form to the "normal" function form ?

Comment: there is no custom reader macros on "lisp" level in clojure. Every reader macro is expanded with a special class inside `clojure.lang.LispReader`. For example regex is expanded by `RegexReader`, so you could try to use it for expansion.. But why do you need it, really?

Comment: and as all of the reader macros are hardcoded and their amount is limited ideologically (and simple), one just learns all of them by heart, so he doesn't bother with "finding out" what does it do, rather he just knows...

Comment: Right, my question was more about discoverability that modifying the behaviour. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @leetwinski I had to accept Andre answer as it provides a way to for a lot of cases that I was wondering about (even if not the example I picked in my question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out what the reader expands to by using `read-string`:

```
(read-string "`(rest ~f)")
=>
(clojure.core/seq
 (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list (quote clojure.core/rest)) (clojure.core/list f)))
(read-string "#(x %&)")
=> (fn* [& rest__92046#] (x rest__92046#))
(read-string "`(~@x)")
=> (clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat x))
(read-string "`(~x)")
=> (clojure.core/seq (clojure.core/concat (clojure.core/list x)))
(read-string "'map")
=> (quote map)
(read-string "#'map")
=> (var map)
(read-string "@x")
=> (clojure.core/deref x)
(binding [*print-meta* true]
  (pr-str (read-string "(def ^:foo x 'map)")))
=> "(def ^{:foo true} x (quote map))"
(read-string "#\"x\"")
=> #"x"
```

In your particular case however: The regex is printed back to you the same way because [that's how it's printed in clojure](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/d5708425995e8c83157ad49007ec2f8f43d8eac8/src/clj/clojure/core_print.clj#L358).

```
(class #"abc")
=> java.util.regex.Pattern
```

Comment: but you can do absolutely the same with `macroexpand`: `(macroexpand '\`(rest ~f))` why bother with `read-string` then?

Comment: In your example the macroexpand does nothing. It's expanded by the reader.

Comment: agreed. So again, why bother with read-string, if quoted expression is shown expanded?

Comment: To not further confuse the readers here on SO with additional quotes :)

Comment: no, you're right, metadata is being eliminated this way (